# How to replace content values in XML files?

Tags: java, xml

What is the best or easiest to use library to perform XML replacement?

Example:

```
<content>
<employee>
  <name>membersound</name>
  <id>1</id>
</employee>
</content>
```

I want to look for the tags

```
<employee><name>
```

and replace what's inside the `<id>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your other question you can try [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) - even it's a Html Parser.

```
Element xmlDoc = // ...


/* If 'name' is not relevant you can use "employee > id" instead */
for( Element e : xmlDoc.select("employee > name + id") )
{
    e.text("30");
}

System.out.println(xmlDoc.select("employee"));
```

**Output:**

```
<employee> 
 <name>
  membersound
 </name> 
 <id>
  30
 </id> 
</employee>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an xslt which would look for the `<employee>` element and replace/delete the `<id>` inside that.